# reconstruct OO.ui.ButtonWidget from $ element

Tags: javascript, mediawiki, oojs-ui

**Setup**

I create an [OO.ui.ButtonWidget](https://doc.wikimedia.org/oojs-ui/master/js/#) in javascript and then display it using $( '#XXX' ).append( mybuttonwidget.$element ).

Lets say the id of this OO.ui.ButtonWidget is YYY.

**What I'm trying to do**

I would like to disable this button latter depending on another event, where I don't have access to the original object mybuttonwidget but can only fetch the node $('YYY').

**Problem**

I would like to use its methods. The following doesn't work:

$( '#YYY' ).setDisabled( true )

The problem is that what I am fetching with $ is not an OO.ui.ButtonWidget but just the node. I assume I either need to recover the object, reconstruct the object or do something similar to infuse() but with a node created in javascript and not in php.

**Questions**

1. **Is there a way of infusing or doing the inverse of mybuttonwidget.$element?**
   so that I can use .setDisabled or any other method of OO.ui.ButtonWidget.
   Looking at the class or parents and I don't see anyway of doing it
2. **Is there an alternative way of doing this?**
   I was thinking of creating a global but I may also need to do the same with a class of ooui objects where determining which one I need to access is not obvious